# flake8: ignore F841 unused variable for double underscore `__` on whole project

Tags: python, flake8

I use double underscore `__` as my dump variable instead of `_`, like so:

```py
needed_value, __ = do_stuff()
use_value(needed_value)
```

However, flake8 complains as it think I'm not using this variable. That's true, but it's on purpose.

Any way to silent flake8 for this particular use case ?

A `#noqa` is possible but I'd like an option to do this on the whole project

Comment: Why can you not use _ ?

Comment: @ApplePie I'm also using django gettext with the usual convention `from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _` which is in conflict with that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the code you pasted does not produce an error

the underlying plugin `pyflakes` will only produce `F841` for normal assignments, not unpackings as you've written

this must mean that you have code that looks like:

```py
def f():
    __ = foo()
```

which in that case, there's no reason for your dump variable and you should rewrite it to remove `__ =`

---

disclaimer: I'm the current flake8 maintainer and I'm one of the pyflakes maintainers

Comment: This is exactly what is happening, thanks